# SQL get string after and before certain string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the string after the first and before the second comma.

For the example below, the output should be `7GWW90330P15`.

In SQL

```
7GWW90330P14,7GWW90330P15,7GWW90330P16,7GWW90330P17
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts at solving this so far? Any idea of which approach you want to take?

Comment: Your values are all the same size, meaning that you can just use `substring()`.  The bigger question is why you are storing multiple values in a single string.  That just poses hard parsing problems.

Comment: @GordonLinoff They're not all the same size: one has a length of zero.

Comment: These values should be split out into separate rows with numbered IDs.

Comment: If you're not going to change the table definition, though, it's probably best to do this at the application level (in your code, after returning the whole string via SQL).

Comment: i though using sub string

Comment: been try 
select right(col, charindex(',', reverse(col)) - 1)
but this gets the last part of string

Answer (score 1):

if it is always second string

```
select  *
from    
    (
        select  col = '7GWW90330P14,7GWW90330P15,7GWW90330P16,,7GWW90330P17'
    ) t
    cross apply
    (
        select  idx1 = charindex(',', col),
            col1 = substring(col, 1, charindex(',', col) - 1)
    ) f
    cross apply
    (
        select  idx2 = charindex(',', col, idx1 + 1),
            col2 = substring(col, idx1 + 1, charindex(',', col) - 1)
    ) s
```

you can extend it to 3rd, 4th etc. But if you are looking for something more general like `nth` string, you need to use a string splitting function.

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
       colname
     , CHARINDEX(',',colname) + 1
     , CHARINDEX(',',colname,CHARINDEX(',',colname)) - 1
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second string and the codes are the same size, then:

```
select (case when str like ',,%'
             then ''
             when str like ',%'
             then substring(str, 2, 12)
             else substring(str, 13, 12)
        end)
```

This doesn't generalize very well, but it does answer your specific question.